# show pagenumbers and filters

Tags: php, magento, attributes, pagination, toolbar

I made a script witch shows the products.

But all products are on one page without the pagenumber toolbar

How can I activate the pagenumbers for the product collection.

I recieve the collection by using:

```
$attribute = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute('manufacturer');
$attribute->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$source = $attribute->getSource();
$id = $source->getOptionId($brand);

//$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());
$products->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => $id));
```

and next I use a foreach coppied from catalog/list.phtml to show all the products

how can I activate the pagenumber toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager');
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager)->setCollection($products)->toHtml();
```

Comment: It shows the toolbar and it is limiting the results but it don't give me pagenumbers. How can I add the pagenumbering?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `catalog/product/list.phtml` instead of copying from it. So you need to have this inside the `<global>`-tag in your `config.xml`:

```
    <blocks>
        <yourmodule>
            <class>Namespace_Yourmodule_Block</class>
        </yourmodule>
    </blocks>
```

You can later add this to your layout XML:

```
<yourmodule_index_view translate="label">
    <!-- other nodes here, for example root where you pick base page layout template -->
    <reference name="content">
        <!-- more blocks here or below if you need anything above or below listing -->
        <block type="yourmodule/list" name="anyName" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</yourmodule_index_view>
```

And in the controller `IndexController.php`

```
public function viewAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

And your block PHP `Block/List.php`

```
class Namespace_Yourmodule_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        // any code here, get the collection in $collection for example..
        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would the config.xml from my module looks like to add the Block?